# Android sending String over UDP

Tags: android, sockets, udp, client

(Old Post)
I´am trying to use a Method to send a String trough UDP on an Android Device (not emulator) 
but the Application does not work and i don´t know why.. Maybe someone have an idea.

In Android Manifest ist the permission for Internet set.

Thanks in advance!

(New Post)
OK the code is working but i´am not so sure if a static variable is the best or the only way to give a variable to a thread. Its just the only solution what i know.

Is there a more professional way to pass variables to thread methods ?

(PS: This is truly the best Forum)

The new Working Code is below:

```
  package com.example.androidudp_client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button button1;
    public EditText editText1;

    public static String sendingWord = "";

    // Method to send Sting to UDP Server
    public static void sendToServer(String nachricht) throws SocketException, IOException, Exception, Throwable
    {
        DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();

        InetAddress ipaddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.178.65");

        byte[] sendData    = new byte[1024];
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        String sentence = nachricht;            
        sendData = sentence.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ipaddr, 8888);

        clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
        clientSocket.close();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         String stringEditText = editText1.getText().toString();
         sendingWord = stringEditText;
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "In editText steht : " + stringEditText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


             Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try 
                        {
                            sendToServer(sendingWord);
                            sendingWord = "";
                        } catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                            String hier2 =  errors.toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception :" + hier2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        } 
                        catch (Throwable th) 
                        {
                            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
                            th.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
                            String hier3 =  errors.toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Throwable :" + hier3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                thread.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Your method only catches IOExceptions, but the "send" method can also throw a SecurityException. Try catching "Exception" to specify which exception you are getting. It is easier to help you if we know what is going wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks you a lot after catching the Exceptions i found out that it was "android block guard policy on network" Problem. The Method disturbed the main Thread so i wrote a thread and it works now. The changed Code is below

Comment: you're welcome. + I added the answer so you can close the question ;-)

Comment: hm sorry i´am completely new to this forum where is the close the question button :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are only catching IOExceptions.
It might be caused by a SecurityException. You can change your "IOException" to "Exception" and see what type of exception is thrown.

**Note: Added this answer because it lead to the fix**